# Company descriptions API?

Tags: data-request, companies

Is there any API or Dataset that gives access to companies and their descriptions?

*Like an "about me" of a company.*

I have used FullContact but I'm looking for something that can do this without web URLs possibly.

Comment: i know you don't want URLs, but this is what humans.txt is for. although the odds of major companies using it are probably slim to none.

Comment: What jurisdiction you are interested in? You can try this [query](http://u01.unigraph.rocks/?q=%7B%0A++subjects(property%3A+%22label%22%2C+text%3A+%22Microsoft%22%2C+lang%3A+%22en%22)+%7B%0A++++instance_of(filter%3A+%22%240+%3D%3D+%6012fa49b4f5%60%22)+%40propagate%0A++++description(lang%3A+%22en%22)%0A++%7D%0A%7D%0A) over Unigraph's data concentrating information from primarily US and UK sources. (Modify the text: "foo") with the company name you are interested in.

Comment: If you are looking for open data on corporates, e.g. names, locations, identifiers, relationships, perhaps [Open Corporates](http://opencorporates.com/)?

Comment: @Michael, can you point me to a jurisdiction on OC with descriptions. Very few registrars provide that, UK for example does not, Infogreffes too and as OC sources are registrars only, they don't have descriptions as a result.

Answer (score 1):

[Unigraph](http://unigraph.io),
[Here](http://try.unigraph.rocks/?q=%7B%0A%20%20subjects(property%3A%20%22label%22%2C%20text%3A%20%22Microsoft%20Corp%22%2C%20lang%3A%20%22en%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20description.en%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A) is a sample query to get the description of Microsoft (try changing the name to any company of interest to you from here:

```
text: "Microsoft Corp"
```

You can also switch between languages for both the request and the answer by changing the **.en** to another iso code, for example **.de** and you will get it in German, if available: "US-amerikanisches Softwareunternehmen"

The datasets from which this information is sourced are listed [here](https://unigraph.io/datasets/)

Answer (score 0):

the [LinkedIn developer API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields) has a "company profile" endpoint

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/company-profile

See these two fields:

> **description**   - Company description. Limit of 500 characters.
>
> **specialties**   - Company specialties. Retrieves information from string input.

*caveat* - *The following company profile fields are available to developers managing company profiles on LinkedIn.*

But if you dig around the API, you might find something that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Knowledge Graph API. (You need to get an API key first, it's free).

In your web browser, call a page like this (example here: "The Coca Cola Company"):

https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?limit=1&indent=True&query=The%20Coca-Cola%20Company&key=AIzaSyBr...

Of course, this link above won't work because I *didn't include my API key* here.

Result (it includes 'name', 'description', 'detailedDescription') :

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
    "goog": "http://schema.googleapis.com/",
    "EntitySearchResult": "goog:EntitySearchResult",
    "detailedDescription": "goog:detailedDescription",
    "resultScore": "goog:resultScore",
    "kg": "http://g.co/kg"
  },
  "@type": "ItemList",
  "itemListElement": [
    {
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/m/03phgz",
        "name": "The Coca-Cola Company",
        "@type": [
          "Thing",
          "Corporation",
          "Organization"
        ],
        "description": "Beverages company",
        "image": {
          "contentUrl": "http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT3CHUgFH_8XM7RTXR3eJExVtPp4URd5oGbCzoJMecUhOiYm_cA",
          "url": "https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_Coca-Cola_Company_logo.svg"
        },
        "detailedDescription": {
          "articleBody": "The Coca-Cola Company, which is headquartered in Atlanta, Georgia, but incorporated in Wilmington, Delaware, is an American multinational beverage corporation, and manufacturer, retailer, and marketer of nonalcoholic beverage concentrates and syrups. ",
          "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Coca-Cola_Company",
          "license": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License"
        },
        "url": "http://www.thecoca-colacompany.com/"
      },
      "resultScore": 1584.391846
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For information on a company 'about' we offer data points for name, title, company size, number of employees, industry, and more. If you are interested in learning more about our dataset you can [visit our site](https://www.peopledatalabs.com/).

Additionally, you can view our 7+ Million Companies Open Sourced Dataset [here.](https://www.peopledatalabs.com/company-dataset?utm_source=stackexchange&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=company-dataset)